# Id name with backwards slash returns null

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an HTML tag with the name `foo\bar` and when trying to get the selector by id name it returns `null`:

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="foo\bar">a</div>
<script>
var esc = document.querySelector('#foo\\bar'); 

console.log(esc); //returns 'null'
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Not sure why this happens, when logging `#foo\\bar` to the console it perfectly outputs the correct id of the tag:

```js
console.log("#foo\\bar");
```

Comment: `var esc = document.querySelector(\`#${CSS.escape('foo\\bar')}\`);` works.

Answer (score 0):

```
var esc = document.getElementById('foo\\bar');
```

Use `getElementById` instead of `querySelector`.

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="foo\bar">a</div>
<script>
var esc = document.getElementById('foo\\bar'); 

console.log(esc); //returns '<div id="foo\\bar">a</div>'
</script>
</body>
</html>
```